# custom single.php post showing up twice

Tags: posts

EDIT:  I am still having this issue which is driving me mad - can any help me please?

Thanks!

I have a custom single-blog.php that has a custom yet basic feed.

Here is the code:

```
    <div class="container">

            <div class="sixteen columns header">

                <div class="six columns alpha">

                    <h4 class="latestTitle">Blog</h4>

                </div>

                <div class="three columns omega offset-by-seven">

                    <div id="rightLinks"><a href="#" class="latestTitle2">Home</a> / <a href="#" class="latestTitle3">Blog</a></div>

                </div>

            </div>

    </div>


<div id="whiteBG">

<div class="container">

    <div class="ten columns">   

<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

    <div <?php post_class() ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">

        <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>

        <?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/inc/meta.php' ); ?>

        <div class="entry">

            <?php the_content(); ?>

            <?php wp_link_pages(array('before' => 'Pages: ', 'next_or_number' => 'number')); ?>

            <?php the_tags( 'Tags: ', ', ', ''); ?>

        </div>

        <?php edit_post_link('Edit this entry','','.'); ?>

    </div>

<?php endwhile; endif; ?>

</div><!-- end ten -->

<div class="six columns">

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>

</div>

</div><!-- end container -->

</div><!-- end whiteBG -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

For some odd reason it shows the same single post twice?  Anyone run into this issue before?

Thanks,

Ben.

This is the meta code:

```
<div class="meta">
        <em>Posted on:</em> <?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?>
    <em>by</em> <?php the_author() ?>
     <?php comments_popup_link('No Comments', '1 Comment', '% Comments', 'comments-link', ''); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't see anything in your code that would cause that. What is in `/inc/meta.php`?

Comment: Hey! That is just meta data! Which is in the above!

Comment: That code isn't the problem, as far as I can tell. There is something going on elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue was that after this if statement on the single.php was the WordPress loop.  Once I removed this it removed the duplicate post underneath the footer - what a fool I feel :(

Hope this helps someone else!

Comment: Someone left a comment stating that this is an very inefficient way of coding. Would you like to show me how you would code it?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help again :) Love this place!

The issues was on the single.php page.  I have this if statement:

```
<?php

$post = $wp_query->post;

if ( in_category('latest-news') ) {

include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/single-latest-news.php'); } 

elseif ( in_category('latest-sermons') ) {

include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/single-latest-sermons.php'); } 

elseif ( in_category('sunday-service') ) {

include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/single-sunday-service.php'); } 

elseif ( in_category('events') ) {

include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/events.php'); } 

elseif ( in_category('blog') ) {

include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/single-blog.php'); } 

else {

include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/single.php');

}

?>
```

but it should be like this without the slash!

```
<?php

$post = $wp_query->post;

if ( in_category('latest-news') ) {

include(TEMPLATEPATH . 'single-latest-news.php'); } 

elseif ( in_category('latest-sermons') ) {

include(TEMPLATEPATH . 'single-latest-sermons.php'); } 

elseif ( in_category('sunday-service') ) {

include(TEMPLATEPATH . 'single-sunday-service.php'); } 

elseif ( in_category('events') ) {

include(TEMPLATEPATH . 'events.php'); } 

elseif ( in_category('blog') ) {

include(TEMPLATEPATH . 'single-blog.php'); } 

else {

include(TEMPLATEPATH . 'single.php');

}

?>
```

Now it does not duplicate the post after the footer and now I can stop sweating in panic!  I have used this method before but not come across this issue.  Hope this answer can help someone else out in the future!

Cheers,

Ben.